# Springboot 2.2.1RELEASE -required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.jdbctemplate'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

Currently am working on **Spring boot version 2.1.7**.Now i moved to **Spring boot version 2.2.1 RELEASE**. when i run  my jar file its failed and its showing an error like

```
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.jdbctemplate'
```

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Java Class file

```
@Component
public class StoredProcedureExecutor
{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate    jdbc;
}
```

**module-context.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
        depends-on="dalConfiguration" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="#{dalConfiguration.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="#{dalConfiguration.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{dalConfiguration.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{dalConfiguration.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="#{dalConfiguration.poolInitialSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="#{dalConfiguration.poolMaxIdle}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="#{dalConfiguration.poolMaxActive}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

> I have tried  below solutions.
>
> - Added `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` dependencies in `pom.xml` file.
> - Remove `.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc` and update    project

But still getting the same error.Is there any spring boot version issue?

Comment: Your @configration file. share it pls

Comment: `@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}` try to add this in @configration file

Comment: why we are create a JdbcTemplate bean   like this.?

Comment: This template needs to be config at the bootstrap time.

Comment: Make sure to remove .m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc and update project.